# Python 3.4.3 save image from url to file using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I tried to make a python program that would allow me to download a jpg file from a website.

Why I'm doing this is really for no reason at all, I just wanted to try it for fun.

Anyways, here is the code:

```
import urllib

a = 1

while a == 1:

    urllib.urlretrieve("http://lemerg.com/data/wallpapers/38/957049.jpg","D:\\Users\\Elias\\Desktop\\FolderName-957049.jpg")
```

(You may have to properly tab it in, it wouldn't let me here)

So basically what I want it to do is to repeatedly download the same file until I close the program. Just don't ask why.

The error code I get is: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
urllib.urlretrieve("http://lemerg.com/data/wallpapers/38/957049.jpg","D:\Users\Elias\Desktop\FolderName-957049.jpg")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Comment: Python3 urllib split into separate modules.  `urllib.request.urlretrieve()`

Answer (score 2):

`urlretrieve()` in Python3 is in the `urllib.request` module.  Do this:

```
from urllib import request

a = 1

while a == 1:

    request.urlretrieve("http://lemerg.com/data/wallpapers/38/957049.jpg","D:\\Users\\Elias\\Desktop\\FolderName-957049.jpg")
```

Comment: This code fails with "NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined."
The correct import statement is import urllib.request and to use urllib.request.urlretrieve.

Comment: @Agargara: Well, I wouldn't say that `import urllib.request` is superior to `from urllib import request`, but I indeed had a typo there. Thanks for pointing it out; I've fixed it.